# Accessing css custom theme constant from code

Tags: codenameone

I wonder whether it's possible to retrieve custom constant values set in the css file from the java code.

I went through the UIManager.themeConstants (as well as themeProps, you never know :)) but I could not find my custom constants in there.

I tried the following:

```css
#Constants {
    --color0: #C4DFE6;
}
```

```java
int color = UIManager.getInstance().getThemeConstant("--color0", 0);
                System.out.println("COLOR0=" + color);
                color = UIManager.getInstance().getThemeConstant("color0", 1);
                System.out.println("COLOR0=" + color);
                color = UIManager.getInstance().getThemeConstant("var(--color0)", 2);
                System.out.println("COLOR0=" + color);
                color = UIManager.getInstance().getThemeConstant("var(color0)", 3);
                System.out.println("COLOR0=" + color);
```

I was hoping one of them to return my value: 0xC4DFE6.

Answer (score 1):

The `--` syntax is a special case for use within the CSS. Try using `MyColor` in the CSS with the same syntax in the Java side and it should work.